# Web cam image capture

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to write an application to capture an image from a webcam. I have written a C++ console application and whilst I can get an image, I have difficulty setting the resolution, I want to get higher resolution images and would like to be able to get 4k from a logitech brio webcam for example.
On Windows 10 with a lower resolution usb camera I was able to get 1280x720. On Windows 11 with a 4k USB camera I am only getting 640x480

Here is my code:

````
#include "vfw.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

#pragma comment(lib, "Vfw32.lib")

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    char device_name[100];
    char filename[100];

    size_t sz = 0;
    char* userpath = nullptr;

    strcpy_s(device_name, "");
    strcpy_s(filename, userpath);
    strncat_s(filename, "\\Documents\\image.bmp", 20);

  // create the preview window 
  HWND hCam = capCreateCaptureWindow (
   "FMCamCapture",
   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
   0, 0, 1024, 768,
   ::GetDesktopWindow(), 0);

  CAPDRIVERCAPS CapDrvCaps;
  capDriverGetCaps(hCam, &CapDrvCaps, sizeof(CAPDRIVERCAPS));

  int driver_number = 0;
  int n = 1;
  //Driver argument
  while (n < argc)
  {

      if (strcmp(argv[n], "/drivernum") == 0)
      {
          // Set device number to specified value
          if (++n < argc) {
              driver_number = atoi(argv[n]);
          }
          else printf("Error: invalid device number");
          if (driver_number <= 0)
              printf("Error: invalid device number");
      }

      if (strcmp(argv[n], "/showdrivers") == 0)
      {
          // Show the list of available drivers and pause and exit
          TCHAR  szDeviceName[80];
          TCHAR  szDeviceVersion[80];

          for (int wIndex = 0; wIndex < 10; wIndex++)
          {
              if (capGetDriverDescription(
                  wIndex,
                  szDeviceName,
                  sizeof(szDeviceName),
                  szDeviceVersion,
                  sizeof(szDeviceVersion)
              ))
              {
                  printf("\nEach Driver may represent a different camera. The default driver is 0. Set a differnt driver to change cameras.\nAvailable Drivers:\n\%i - %s\n", wIndex, szDeviceName);
                  // Append name to list of installed capture drivers
                  // and then let the user select a driver to use.
              }
          }
          system("pause");
          return 0;
      }

      n++;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "Saved file location: %s\n", filename);

  CAPTUREPARMS captureParms;

  BITMAPINFO bMInfo;
  // connect to the first Driver 
  // for other cameras try index 
  // 1, 2, in place of the 0 below 
  if(capDriverConnect(hCam, driver_number))
  {

      capGetVideoFormat(hCam, &bMInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
      //printf("height %ld", bMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight);
      //printf("width %ld", bMInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth);
      //printf("bisize %lu", bMInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
      //printf("compression %lu", bMInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression);

      bMInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = 1280;
      bMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = 720;
      bMInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
      //bMInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = (bMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight) * (((bMInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth * 2) * bMInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4;
      bMInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

      if (capSetVideoFormat(hCam, &bMInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFO))) {
          //printf("set res success setvidformat");
      }

    capFileSaveDIB(hCam, filename);

    //printf("Saved!");
    capDriverDisconnect(hCam);
  }

  else 
  {

    printf("Check camera?");

  }

  DestroyWindow(hCam);

  return 0;

}```
````

Comment: interesting.. i will follow for the answer

Comment: VfW is getting old (30 years this year). Have you tried a more contemporary technology, such as [`MediaCapture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) instead?